# How to run jQuery function on form submit?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that I want to run after a form is successfully submitted. The function fades in a screen overflow then displays items in a list before redirecting to another url.

Here's the script:

```
    <script >
      function startCheck() {
    var e = $(".overlay-checker"),
        t = $(".overlay-checker-points > li");
    for (t.hide(), e.fadeIn(), i = 0; i < t.length; i++) setTimeout(function() {
        $(".overlay-checker-points").find(":hidden").first().fadeIn()
    }, 1500 * (i + 1));
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = $(".redirectNow").attr("href")
    }, 1500 * t.length + 2e3)
    }
   </script>
```

How do I run the above function after a form is successfully submitted?

Comment: Maybe by using the submit event? How do you run it now? Post a [mcve] please

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge of jQuery to formulate anything close to a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following listener:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e){
   // Prevent form submission
   e.preventDefault();
   // Show loader
   // Optional, but showing that something's happening is probably good
   // Assuming you have some element with class "loader" hidden...
   $(".loader").show();
   // Submit form via ajax call
   $.ajax({
      url: "path_to_your_file.php",
      type: "post",
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      success: function(data){
         // Form submitted
         // Call script here 
      },
      error: function(data){
         // Handle error here
      },
      complete: function(){
         // Will be called after success or error
         // Hide loader (if shown before ajax call above)
         $(".loader").hide();
      }
   });
})
```

And on your server side, you can retrieve your form's inputs using `$_POST["name"]`

**EDIT:**

This is what your HTML form would look like:

```
<form>
   <input type="email" name="useremail" placeholder="Email address" required>
   <!-- Add any other input, select, textarea of your liking -->
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You'll retrieve the input in your PHP file like this:

```
$email = $_POST["useremail"];
```

Comment: Thanks @Will. If I follow your example how do I format the form html? What about the action attribute?

Comment: You can leave out the action attribute since the form will be submitted via ajax. I'm updating my response to show you how to put that form together.